# HTML program for generating output in the third box automatically as we enter the values in the first two text boxes?

Tags: javascript, html

I've three textboxes and three radio buttons on my page.I have written the programme for Arithmetic operation i.e. add,sub,mul etc. Now I want to generate the result automatically in the third text box when i enter the values in the first two text box without clicking any button.i.e. if addition radio button is selected and i enter the value in the first two text boxes i should get the add result in the third text box without again checking the radio button. Please some one help and tell me how to do it?

Comment: @Anish: please don't format non-code as code. "Radio buttons" and "text boxes" are words, not code!

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is listening for a change or keyup event on the input fields.

The change event will trigger once the textfield loses the focus, the keyup event will trigger when a key on the keyboard was pressed and is not anymore pressed. Keyup in this case makes more sense in my opinion.

Following code should keep you going:

```
function recalculate() {
  // recalculate your operation here
}

// assign a keyup handler to your fields
document.all.inputFieldA.onkeyup = recalculate;
document.all.inputFieldB.onkeyup = recalculate;
```